# Perturbation theorem of Weyl

Tags: hilbert-spaces, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics

Does anyone know where to find something about the perturbation theorem of Weyl, preferably 
on the internet. The theorem I'm talking about states:
let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space, and let $B$ be compact with respect to $A$.
Then the essential spectrum of $A+B$ is equal to the essential spectrum of $A$.
Also, what does this have to do with quantum mechanics? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably also [here](http://www.math.ou.edu/~cremling/teaching/lecturenotes/fa-new/ln15.pdf) you can find something.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at Reed M., Simon B., Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics:
Vol. 4 Analysis of Operators, XIII 4.